# Reading sensor data over MUX

Tags: temperature-sensor, multiplexer

I will start by saying I am very new to using Arduino.  The project I am planning is to create several arrays of sensors (each array will consist of 4 DS18B20 sensors and one temperature/humidity sensor) and using a MUX connected to Arduino I want to read the data from each [ten] array.  I have found sketches I can modify to do this task in a continuous cycle but I need to be able to display data from an array for an extended time period of several minutes.  My Arduino will output to a 3.2" LCD so there is only enough screen space to show data for one array at a time.

Comment: Push the "edit" button and add more info or at least ask a question.

Comment: DS18B20 sensors don't need a mux. You can have 40 DS18B20's on a single line. As to the "question". You could add some buttons below the LCD to select which array data to show.

Comment: You have posted a statement, not a question. You could post your code, perhaps? Also state what happens, and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The DS18B20 is a [1-Wire](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/OneWire) device and doesn't require a multiplexer, each device has its own address on the bus and you can connect a lot of them with a single wire. Depending on the humidity sensor you pick you may be able to use the same bus for it as well.

It is harder to find 1-Wire humidity sensors, but you could use a [DS2438 Smart Battery Monitor](http://electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/1-wire-technology-simplifies-humidity-and-temperature-measurement) which also includes an ADC to give you values from an analog humidity sensor.

The challenge of designing your project will be setting up an easy to understand display and controlling how/when it changes.